# Как соединить wav и mp4 файлы на С++?

Tags: android, c++, unreal-engine-4, wav, mp4

Какие есть библиотеки для работы с `wav` и `mp4` файлами на C++/Android и как с ними работать?

Есть `mp4` файл на android, по пути

> emulated/storage/0/Movies/MyVideo.mp4

У данного файла нужно заменить звуковую дорожку на другую в формате `wav`

Разработку веду на `C++` в `Unreal engine 4`

Если не сложно, добавьте небольшой кусок кода, который показывает как прочесть mp4 и wav файл и дальнейшую работу с ними

Comment: https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4

Comment: Libav и FFmpeg (libav туда входит), только на чистом Си. Но ничего, закинь хэдеры в extern "C" { } и будет работать. Либо ещё libvlc (но она, опять же, использует ffmpeg). Просто по FFmpeg и Libav какая-никакая, а документация на доксигене есть, а вот у других я особо не нашёл.